# Nhibernate 3.0 Complex queries

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I need to perform queries that can be very complex, and I wanna make sure linq/queryOver can handle it.

what's the limitations and abilities I can't get with linq and can get with sql/hql ?

Comment: Is there a *specific* concern you have?

Comment: many joins, some oracle hints, tables that relate to each other without fk constraint due to db that support history for everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a list of limitations, other than the list of open bugs in Jira.

if you are performing complex queries, HQL is usually the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

However complex the query is you cna ultimately convert it toa QueryOver it might just get a little difficult and hard to read, but then you have a very strongly typed API.

Having said that you can always use HQL on your object model to achieve the same.

```
 Session.CreateQuery("").List<>();
```

if that is difficult then there is always SQL to do the same.

```
 Session.CreateSqlQuery("").ExecuteUpdate<>();
 Session.CreateSqlQuery("").List<>();
```